# ngSelected does not update ngModel [AngularJS]

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel

Below I have the following select list. The ngSelected does correctly select the value in the expression, but the model for the select does not update accordingly. I can select the "High" Value, and when the ngSelected triggers, the empty value is displayed but the model stays as "High".

Anybody know how to programmatically set ngModel after ngSelected is triggered? The expression in ngSelected comes from a directive on a div, so I cannot attach an ngChange on it.

```
<select class="form-control" name="alertLevel-{{$index}}" ng-model="template.service.readings[$index].repeatBreachAlert.repetitiveAlertLevel" title="Please select an alert level">
      <option ng-selected="template.service.firstLevelMessage.below.messages | messagesLength.length === 0" value=""></option>
      <option value="Valid">Valid</option>
      <option value="High">High Alert</option>
      <option value="Low">Low Alert</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used this to set the model in the view which solves this answer:

```
<span class="ng-hide">
   {{((template.service.firstLevelMessage.above.messages | messagesLength).length === 0  && template.service.readings[$index].repeatBreachAlert.repetitiveAlertLevel !== 'Valid' ? template.service.readings[$index].repeatBreachAlert.repetitiveAlertLevel = '' : '' }}
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is taken from [angular official site](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected/#overview).

> Note: ngSelected does not interact with the select and ngModel
>   directives, it only sets the selected attribute on the element. If you
>   are using ngModel on the select, you should not use ngSelected on the
>   options, as ngModel will set the select value and selected options.

That being said. **You should initialize your model in your controller** and remove the ng-selected directive.

Something like this would work:

```
function initializeModel() {
  for (let i; i < whatEverMyIterationLooksFor; i++) { // I suppose you are using ng-repeat in template so here you should iterate through the relevant scope.
    const shouldBeEmpty = template.service.firstLevelMessage.below.messages || messagesLength.length === 0; // You also had a typo here with the OR operator.

    if (shouldBeEmpty) {
      template.service.readings[i].repeatBreachAlert.repetitiveAlertLevel = null;
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: This will only work on initialization or whenever this function is called. Also not a typo, just a custom filter

Comment: Thank you for the info about ngSelected though.

Comment: Alternatively you can use `ng-init` to initialize your model in view but it's not such a good practice.